# Deploy 2 Sites on same Apache server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, apache, deployment

I need to deploy my Rails app to a server that is already serving a PHP site at its root. I can't touch the existing site, and I have to deploy my app at a sub-url or sub-domain, ie `xx.xx.xx.xx/rails` or `rails.xx.xx.xx.xx`.

The Apache config I normally use to deploy my app:

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>

      ServerName localhost

      DocumentRoot "C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/projects/app_name/public"
      <Directory "C:/RubyStack-3.2.5-0/projects/app_name/public">
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
      </Directory>

      RewriteEngine On

      RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
      RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ balancer://app_balancers%{REQUEST_URI} [P,QSA,L]

      <Proxy balancer://app_balancers>
        BalancerMember http://localhost:3001/
        BalancerMember http://localhost:3002/
      </Proxy>

      # Support for far-futures expires header
      <LocationMatch "^/assets/.*$">
        Header unset ETag
        FileETag None
        # RFC says only cache for 1 year
        ExpiresActive On
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
      </LocationMatch>
    </VirtualHost>
```

How could I change this configuration to serve that folder from a sub-url or subdomain? A `RedirectMatch` won't work because it would also route people away from the existing PHP site, right?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way would be to do name-based virtual hosting, using a subdomain as you suggested. So where you write:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

Simply enter your subdomain instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName mysubdomain.mycompany.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Apache should then separate any requests to that subdomain from the 'main' virtualhost automatically.

**edit:**

Alternatively it is possible to mount your rails app to a subdirectory as well (assuming you're using Passenger.) Here's an example based on my own local staging environment. I got this working by following the instructions at the [Phusion website](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#deploying_rails_to_sub_uri)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost

  # We will mount our application under http://localhost/myapp
  RailsBaseURI /myapp

  # This can be anywhere on the system, I just happened to use /home/www
  <Directory /home/www/myapp>
    # Here you can add any directives necessary for your app, like for example..
    SetEnv GEM_HOME /home/user/.rvm/gems/ree-1.8.7-2012.02
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Now you have to do one more thing, and that's make /home/www/myapp a link to the public dir of the actual application. So let's say you have the application in your own homedir you would have to type this:

```
cd /home/www
ln -s /home/myuser/myapp/public myapp
```

If you then type ls -l it should show:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 myuser myuser 18 Jun 10 16:41 devb -> /home/myuser/myapp/public
```

I think that should be it.

Comment: See, the problem is that it's on company intranet, so it doesn't actually have a domain name, just an IP address :/

Comment: Can you ask your company network guy to add DNS entries to the internal DNS server at your company?

Comment: Due to the wonders of corporate bureaucracy, I seriously doubt it. I submitted a request to get one of our servers a static IP address over 3 weeks ago and it's still sitting in some senior manager's inbox waiting to be approved. So no, unfortunately :/

Comment: It is also possible with a little more work to mount the application on a sub url. I edited the answer to include that as well, hope it works for you.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, but I am on a Windows environment. I assume the `RailsBaseURI` directive is specific to Passenger?