# Force rails to ignore "real" path in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, link-to

I am using rails on an Apache server. I can't *install* my rails app on the public root directory. So I have it on `/web`. With an .htaccess I rewrite any URL from `/` to `/web`. For example `/something` will be `/web/something` and so on.

Now, in my app, I build my links with the url helper `link_to`:

```
link_to "Timeline", timeline_path
```

But it yields `/web/en/timeline` instead of `/en/timeline`. The *en* is just the locale to work with i18n.

Is there a way to force `link_to` to create just the */en/timeline* path or do I have to write it manually? Like so:

```
link_to "Timeline", "/en/timeline"
```

Edit: To add info as JoseE ask.

This is my routes.rb file:

```
  get "home/index"
  root:to => 'home#index'
  match '/:locale' => 'home#index'

  scope "/:locale" do
    match 'timeline' => 'timeline_articles#index'
    match 'home' => 'home#index'
  end
```

Comment: For starters, it'd be useful to see your config/routes.rb file.

Comment: This answer may help: (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12110334/deploy-2-sites-on-same-apache-server)

Comment: @IanKenney I was looking and reading that answer, but on the [phusion documentation](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html#_deploying_a_ruby_on_rails_1_x_or_2_x_but_not_rails_gt_3_x_application) it says that that will just work for rails 1.x 2.x **but not 3.x**. I actually use 3.x.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be an issue related to the rails stack. /web seems to be appended to your domain. (and isn't that the intended effect you wanted in the 1st place?), This problem is related to Apache, so I strongly suggest to you that you add that Tag to this question.

Comment: This seems like an apache config issue, not Rails.

Comment: My hosting provider says me it is not possible to do this on a VPS. Is there any other solution?